# S3 Caching on Kaniko

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, cicd, kaniko

I am using kaniko to build images inside gitlab CI. I want to cache the layers on S3 but get an error:

`dial tcp: lookup s3 on xxx.xx.xxx: no such host`

The arguments I pass to Kaniko:

```
"--cache=true --cache-ttl=24h --compressed-caching=false --use-new-run --cache-repo s3://bucket-name/cache"
```